# Find a Word check box control by its Tag property using Open XML SDK

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk, word-2010, word-2013

I have a Word 2013 document containing a check box control. I have set this checkbox's *Tag* property to `fooCheckBox`:

[image: Screenshot showing a Word 2013 checkbox's properties]

Now I would like to programmatically find and manipulate that particular checkbox using Open XML SDK 2.5. I know how to find/enumerate checkboxes, but I don't know how to find a particular `SdtContentCheckBox` by its *Tag* property:

Given a `WordprocessingDocument doc`, how can I retrieve a specific `SdtContentCheckBox`'s by its *Tag* property?

(I have working code, which I am posting as an [answer (see below)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30849251/240733). However, I have no idea if this is the right way to do it; so if someone knows a better, more proper way, I'd like to see how it's done.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, a `SdtContentCheckBox` object's `.Parent` property references a `SdtProperty` collection which can be queried for a `Tag` descendant.

I do not understand the logic behind this object modelling, but it can be used to get the job done:

```
// using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
// using System.Diagnostics;
// using System.Linq;

SdtContentCheckBox TryGetCheckBoxByTag(WordprocessingDocument doc, string tag)
{
    foreach (var checkBox in doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<SdtContentCheckBox>())
    {
        var tagProperty = checkBox.Parent.Descendants<Tag>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (tagProperty != null)
        {
            Debug.Assert(tagProperty.Val != null);
            if (tagProperty.Val.Value == tag)
            {
                // a checkbox with the given tag property was found
                return checkBox;
            }
        }
    }
    // no checkbox with the given tag property was found
    return null;
}
```